# Bootstrap Vue Modal ok button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Hello iam using a **bootstrap vue modal** but i want to change the name of the buttons make ok button show submit and cancle show close in the footer but i have no access to them where can i find them.
This is what i have

```
<button v-b-modal.modal-close_visit class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Close</button>

<b-modal id="modal-close_visit" @hidden="resetClose">
  <template #modal-title
><p class="text-uppercase">
  Close {{ close_visit.patient_name }}'s Visit
</p></template>
</b-modal>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite the standard footer with your own:

```
<b-modal>
    <template #modal-footer>
        <button v-b-modal.modal-close_visit class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1">Close</button>
        <button v-b-modal.modal-close_visit class="btn btn-success btn-sm m-1">Submit</button>
    </template>
</b-modal>
```